# Working with MySQL Polygon Fields in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a MySQL table with a polygon field. Can I use CakePHP to save/edit records?

The only working way I found is to use raw MySQL queries. Which isn't very nice, because Validation and BeforeSave/AfterSave will not be executed.

Another more cake-way approach I've tried failed.

```
$polygonString = 'PolygonFromText('POLYGON((x x, x x, x x))')';

$area = $areasTable->newEntity();
$area = $areasTable->patchEntity(
    $area,
    [
        'area' => $polygonString,
    ]
);
$areasTable->save($area);
```

This will result in the following query.

```
INSERT INTO areas (area)
    VALUES ('PolygonFromText(''POLYGON((x x,x x))'')');
```

That is because CakePHP thinks it is all text. But `PolygonFromText` is a mysql function....

Comment: No time for a proper answer right now... what you need is a custom database type that supports converting data to expressions, see **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types** and **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#mapping-custom-datatypes-to-sql-expressions**. And make sure that you implement proper validation for the data is passed to `patchEntity`, otherwise this can easily lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: I'm on the go again, just a quick additional note that somehow got lost in my previous comment, not only should there be proper validation, but you also need to make sure that you are binding the input values properly into the generated expression, ie do not simply create a concatenated SQL string and turn it into an expression.